# Obtaining data from ControlTemplate/DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm looking for advice, my problem is obtaining data(written text by user) from TextBox which is allocated by ControlTemplate in RadioButton. RadioButton is created programmatically in ScrollViewer.

XAML:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Name="rbTemplate" TargetType="RadioButton">
        <RadioButton>   
            <TextBox></TextBox>
        </RadioButton>
    </ControlTemplate> 
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Just [Bind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the TextBox to a property in your ViewModel like in [MvvM](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/680271/Simplest-MVVM-Ever), job done.

Answer (score 0):

As @XAMlMAX has correctly mentioned, in WPF we use data binding to deal with obtaining data from the UI. You can find out the full story in the [Data Binding Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN. However, in short, you need to add a property to receive the data and then data bind it to the `TextBox.Text` property:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Name="rbTemplate" TargetType="RadioButton">
        <RadioButton>   
            <TextBox Text="{Binding YourStringProperty}" />
        </RadioButton>
    </ControlTemplate> 
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Then in your code behind or view model, you can obtain the entered text from the `YourStringProperty` property.

Comment: I forgot to say that i'm using silverlight. I was searching and trying to implement property, but still i'm confused. Can i ask for more explanations ?